# Why do some AWS KMS keys only show Policy View?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I have two KMS "Customer Managed Keys" in the same region.

One of them has a button that switches between Default View and Policy View...

[image]

And the other only shows Policy View...

[image]

What is the explanation for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appreciate this is a couple of years old but came across it while looking for confirmation myself.

It appears to be the difference between those created via the AWS console and those created via the AWS CLI or an SDK.

Those created using the AWS console prompt for the key administrators and users and display the "default view" when viewing/editing those keys.

Those created with the AWS SDK (via Terraform in my case) only display the "policy view".

And a quick test with the AWS CLI (e.g. `aws kms create-key --description "test via CLI"`) results in the same with only the "policy view" available.

Comment: Mystery solved.